# Constants in Hardy-Littlewood inequality for Dini derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

I've been reading through some notes on Terence Tao's blog (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/).

Lemma 56 states that for $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous, monotonically increasing function that the Dini derivatives satisfy

$m(\{x \in [a,b]: D^+(F)(x)>\lambda \}) \leq \frac{F(b)-F(a)}{\lambda}$

(where $D^+(F)(x)$ is defined as $\limsup_{h\to 0^+} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$)

It is mentioned that in the case that $F$ is not assumed to be continuous that one needs some constant

$m(\{x \in [a,b]: D^+(F)(x)>\lambda\}) \leq C\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{\lambda}$

One can prove this, for example, for $C=3$ with the Vitali covering lemma.

I'd like to construct a function $F$ which actually requires some $C>1$ for the inequality to hold, but am having some trouble doing so. It seems to me that to alter the value of $D^+(F)$ on a measurable set we need to add discontinuities to our function on some countable dense set. For example, we could pick some enumeration of the rationals between $[a,b]$ and alter a function $F$ by adding a jump of size $\frac{1}{2^n}$ at each such rational. However, doing any calculations with this new function seems very difficult to me. Does anyone know of any monotonic functions $F$ which require a constant $C>1$ for the above inequality to hold?

Comment: How does one prove the discontinuous case when $F$ is not continuous, using Vitali-type covering lemma? I followed the hint in the note and tried to construct an open cover of the  compact set $K \subset  \{ x \in (a,b): \overline{D^+} F(x) > \lambda \}$ with total measure less than or equal to $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{\lambda}$, but struggles to find one. Can you provide some hint on that?